# Error when trying to start iptables

Tags: iptables, ftp

I have tried to install vsftpd and I added this line to my iptables:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

However, when I start iptables. I get the following error:

```
Flushing firewall rules:                                   [  OK  ]
Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: mangle filter nat         [  OK  ]
Unloading iptables modules:                                [  OK  ]
Applying iptables firewall rules: iptables-restore: line 1 failed [FAILED]
```

And there is only the above line in the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file - what have I done wrong?

Comment: You are not supposed to edit `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` by hand, and the name of the chain name you used is reserved for RedHat/Fedora automatic firewall configuration.

Comment: I see, so what would the handle for CentOS be? In addition, how do you enable port 21 to be unblocked by the iptables? Apologies, I am new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that the `RH-Firewall-1-INPUT` chain isn't standard so you have to create it. Having a single line in your iptables config isn't ideal either. A fairly basic `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` is

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [486:51620]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p ah -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -d 224.0.0.251 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

You should add your rule to the above before the REJECT line.